# Simplification Made to Gain Equation

Tags: mosfet

I was watching one of Razavi's videos

https://youtu.be/pK2elUcXWzs?list=PLiDoPUX9nLkIw9EnIv_3K19wlcyJ6msYd&t=2309
Skip to 38:30

He did this:
[image]

He justified this approximation by saying that gm1ro1 and gm1ro2 >> 1. But how does that get rid of the extra +ro1 at the end?? **Why is it not there in the end?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since \$g_{m1}r_{o1} \gg 1\$, we can neglect the 1 inside bracket. Then, 
$$R=g_{m1}r_{o2}r_{o1}+r_{o1}=(g_{m1}r_{o2}+1) r_{o1}$$

Since \$g_{m1}r_{o2} \gg 1\$,

$$R= g_{m1}r_{o2}r_{o1}$$